# Mysql InnoDB locking for atomic read

Tags: mysql, jdbc, locking, innodb

I have a website, which has a method (in the backing bean) which does several READ-requests (to check e.g. the users' rights) and then to insert some data.

the prodecure looks like this:

```
1.) SELECT * FROM userLocks (table which logs the users which are exclusively working on a topic, to avoid redundancy). it checks if there is currently no lock (user working) for the topic.
2.) SELECT * FROM ... (some other selects for further checking)
3.) INSERT INTO userLocks (curUser, timeout) values (...) (if everything was ok, create a new lock for the current user for the topic)
```

The problem I am facing now is: Between the first select and the insert many other users can request the same website which manipulates the data of the table userLocks. It seems to be not thread-safe.

Is there a solution for this problem? all I need is that all the used Tables are locked during this procedure for other users. (the other request just should wait until the lock is released, which dont take more than half a second...)

(I use InnoDB)

Comment: Did you turn off autocommit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you need to research SQL Transactions a little and row and table locks for InnoDB. This was an article that helped me https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/introduction_to_transaction_locks_in